# Work with Conversion of decimal numbers

Tags: c

May be it is one of the simplest things for C programmers but I really can't get it.

```
unsigned char Value[4]; 
unsigned long ulVer = 00010001;
unsigned long uSize = sizeof(ulVer);
memcpy(Value, &ulVer, uSize);
memcpy(&ulVer, Value, uSize); 
printf("%d",ulVer);
```

Why ulVer is 4097, not 10001 ?

Comment: You should declare `Value` as : `unsigned char Value[sizeof(unsigned long)]; `

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because an integer constant that starts with 0 is considered to be octal (base 8). So a number 10001 (in octal) == 4097 in decimal.

Answer (score 5):

00010001;  is an octal constant because it starts with 0.
You need to write 10001 if that's what you want in decimal.

Answer (score 1):

In C, octal constants start with 0. For your code snippet to work, try using 10001